# Passing react-navigation TabNavigator to react-redux's connect error

Tags: android, react-native, redux, react-navigation

Trying to set up a main App component which is responsible for showing either the Login screen or the whole app if user is logged.

The only doubt I have is about saving connect()'s return value (should be the HOC I want) in a variable to use in the main EntryPoint

[image: Error]

What is it that I'm getting so wrong?

---

```
const MAIN_TABS_OPTIONS = {
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    swipeEnabled: false,
    animationEnabled: false
}

store = createStore(PACKED_REDUCERS, applyMiddleware(thunk, logger));
store.dispatch(registerAuthStateListener())
store.dispatch(fetchWishes())

class _App extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super (props)
    }

    render () {
        const { AUTH } = this.props

        RealApplication = StackNavigator({
            Index: {
                screen: TabNavigator({
                    Home: {
                        screen: Home
                    },
                    Desideri: {
                        screen: WishesDashboard
                    }
                }, MAIN_TABS_OPTIONS)
            }
        }, {
            initialRouteName: 'Index',
            header: null
        })

        if (AUTH.user)
            return <RealApplication />
        else
            return <Login />
    }
}

const App = 
connect(
    (state) => {
        return {
            AUTH: state.auth
        }
    },
    (dispatch) => {
        return {
            registerAuthStateListener: () => dispatch (registerAuthStateListener()),
            fetchWishes: () => dispatch (fetchWishes())
        }
    }
)(_App)


export default class EntryPoint extends React.Component {
    constructor () {
        super()
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <App />
            </Provider>
        )
    }
}
```

---

Comment: connect  react-navigation with redux store .... create Navigation reducer

Comment: can you explain this a little further? I'm using the exact same technique in another project and it works fine